# Use result from one XSLT transformation in another

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT (2.0) and I encountered following situation. I have XML input that looks like this:

```xml
<root>
    <elem name="elemName1">
         <subel1>value</subel1>  
         <subel1>value2</subel1>  
    </elem>
    <elem name="elemName2">
         <subel1>value</subel1>  
         <subel1>value2</subel1>  
    </elem>
    <elem name="elemName3">
         <subel2>value</subel2>  
         <subel2>value2</subel2>  
    </elem>

    <referencing>
         <something type="elemName1"/>
    </referencing>
    <referencing>
         <something type="elemName2"/>
    </referencing>
    <referencing>
         <something type="elemName3"/>
    </referencing>
</root>
```

I need two things:

1. change attribute name of all `<elem>` elements that contain `<subel1>` from `elemNameX` to `newelemNameX`
2. change all `<something>`'s `type` attributes to reference these new names.

I've managed to do first step, but I struggle with the second

I was thinking going through all `\\something\@type` and trying to find `\\elem[@name='newelemX']`. But I can't match modified `<elem>` created in first step.

**Is it possible to match results of one template in different template?**

Comment: Do you need to be concerned with any attributes other than the ones presented in the example?  Specifically, do you need to provide for copying any attributes of `<elem>` or `<something>` elements that you have not portrayed?

Comment: Your example XML is not well formed, on account of the `<referencing>` elements not being closed.  I assume you intended some of those start tags to instead be end tags.

Comment: Yes, `<something>` has other attributes that I need to keep. (<elem> is little more complicated in practice than in my example. Actually, I'm creating new element `<elem>` with name `newelemNameX` and I reference `elemNameX` from `newelemNameX`, but since I solved this part, I simplified the question).

Comment: And you are right about `<referencing>`, I'll fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking going through all \something\@type and trying to find
>   \elem[@name='newelemX']. But I can't match modified  created in
>   first step.
>
> Is it possible to match results of one template in different template?

If you have assigned the result of evaluating the template to a variable then yes, it is possible (in XSLT 2.0).  You can do this, for example, by applying templates to the node sequence recorded in the variable.  But you don't need to go to that kind of trouble if you're willing to allow a bit of duplication of the logic.  You can do *that* even in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Identity transform for where there is no more specific match -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- modified "name" attributes for certain "elem" elements -->    
  <xsl:template match="elem[subel1]/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">new<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- "type" attributes of "something" elements -->    
  <xsl:template match="something/@type">
    <!-- need to capture the current value for use in a test expression -->
    <xsl:variable name="current_value" select="." />
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
      <!-- insert "new" into the value where needed (logic duplicated here) -->
      <xsl:if test="/descendant::elem[@name=$current_value]/subel1">new</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't realize I could write the `<xsl if test=...>` to match original document before any changes, that did the trick.